# Display a pdf pages rerendred with visualforce horizontally

Tags: visualforce, pdf, css

I have a visualforce rerenderAs pdf, my question is if there is a way to display my pdf pages horizontally, not vertically.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about landscape?

If so you can:

```
<head>

<style>

@page {

size:landscape;

}

</style>

</head>
```

To orient it is landscape mode